# Postgres/Redshift: Extract Quarter and Year from date column for a group by in one call?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I was wondering if there was a way to extract a year and Quarter from a date column in one call from Redshift/Postgres DB in order for me to group by on them?

Since query speed is very important to me, I currently have the year and column as two columns along with the date which I am not happy about, as I have this information in the date column however they make queries almost twice as fast if I join on them versus using two `extract()` calls on the date to get the year and quarter.

e.g

```
Select SUM(some_column), 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM the_date) as year_date,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM the_date) as q_date
FROM table
Group by year_date, q_date;
```

vs

```
Select SUM(some_column), 
year_date,
q_date
FROM table
Group by year_date, q_date;
```

I would be looking for something like this:

```
Select SUM(some_column), 
extract(Year | Quarter from the _date) AS year_q
FROM table
Group by year_q;
```

I tried the to_char method but it's slower than both options above.

Thanks

Comment: How many records do you have? How many nodes in your cluster? Are you trying to populate a dashboard?

Comment: Around 8 Billion records, 4 8xlarge nodes and no it's just a query for a front end. Sometimes I want to see results by week, quarter, month etc over a span of several years. Etc the query in my question.

Comment: You should try to use the WINDOW functions (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html) instead of the GROUP BY ones.

Comment: I've never heard of windows before and just tried putting together a query based on the documenting however it seems to be a lot slower in my case than using a group by.

`Select EXTRACT(YEAR FROM the_date) as year_date,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM the_date) as q_date,
sum(some_column) over (partition by year_date, q_date order by year_date, q_date rows unbounded preceding) as sum
FROM table
order by year_date, q_date;`

Or am I using it wrong?

Comment: If you are using a function such as EXTRACT for your window, Redshift needs to scan over all the data to build it, which is slower. You can try to add these columns to the data with Create Table as Select (CTAS) deep copy and it should make your queries much more efficient.

Comment: How about concat(extract(),extract()) and group by 1 ? Will that be slow ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is for analytics purpose. 
It's much better to materialize separate columns for the year, quarter and year-quarter from the_date column, as is suggested in one of the comments. That way you can use these to group by year, quarter number across years or by quarters. But what columns you materialize really depends on the analytics requirements.

To answer your specific question, lets say you have a table as below.

```
create table source_table (
    some_column         int,
    the_date            timestamp
);
```

You can use a CTAS query of the following form to create a table suitable for analytics from this.

```
create table analytics_table as (
    select
        some_column,
        extract(year from the_date) as year,
        extract(quarter from the_date) as quarter,
        extract(year from the_date) || '-' || extract(quarter from the_date) as year_quarter
    from
        source_table
);
```

On this table you could then run queries of the following form, which should go through much faster.

```
select
    year,
    sum(some_column)
from
    analytics_table
group by
    year
;

select
    year_quarter,
    sum(some_column)
from
    analytics_table
group by
    year_quarter
;
```